# Mangled View Frame with Split View Controller

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, frame

In my application which features a split view controller I have a loading view. My Root View Controller is a subclass of `UITableViewController`; while loading data I save self.view and transition it out with the loading view:

```
- (void)loadingWillBegin {
    self.cachedView = self.view;
    self.progressBar.progress = 0.0;
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:self.loadingView duration:1.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown completion:NULL];
    self.view = self.loadingView;
}

- (void)loadingDidFinish {
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.loadingView toView:self.cachedView duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:NULL];
    self.view = cachedView;
}
```

The transitions work fine, but after the loading view is paged out the frame of the table view is all screwed up. THere is a black bar at the top of the same size as a status bar (I did clear the Status Bar Simulated Metrics), and the view extends below the actual bottom of the screen. The frame seems to be the same as the `loadingView`; on that view I have set the *iPad Simulated Metrics* to `Master`, which led to the view being about 820px tall. Regardless of that option's setting, Xcode 4 is not allowing me to change the frame of the view in the Size Inspector.

What should I do about the frame of the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On completion of your animation you could manually set the correct frame.

```
[UIView transitionFromView:self.loadingView toView:self.cachedView duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:^(BOOL finished){self.cachedView.frame = /* Insert appropriate frame here. */;}];
```